# Using PHP Form to Embed Video

Tags: php, forms, video, embed

I want to use a PHP form to embed a video onto a web page. Not sure why this isn't working as the page source has the embed code but nothing is showing up on the page. Here's the PHP I'm using:

test.php

```
<html>
<head></head>

<form action="" method="post">
Embed Code: <input type="text" name="embedCode" />
<input type="submit" />
</form>

<?php echo $_POST['embedCode']; ?>

</html>
```

The 'embedCode' should be able to handle any generic video embedding code such as  or  and shouldn't be specific to YouTube or anything else.

Comment: You have a syntax error on this line: `<?php echo $_POST['url]; ?>`

Answer (score 1):

The URL part must be the src of the embed. For a youtube video it would be like this:

```
<html>
<head></head>

<form action="" method="post">
URL: <input type="text" name="url" />
<input type="submit" />
</form>

<iframe width="560" height="315" src="<?php echo $_POST['url']; ?>" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

</html>
```

That should work. There are a few problems with this simple solution though:

- you're trying to echo something that doesn't exist in most cases (when the page is loaded without the form being posted) -> check if the the form has been posted first
- there is no input validation on what links are posted. You might want to make sure it's a valid (youtube?) link that's being posted before embedding it

Cheers

Comment: Well, I guess the name URL was a little misleading. What I'm really posting into that form is the entire embed code, not just the url. I'm not really concerned about form validation and I might add an if(isSet()) later.

Answer (score 0):

In your code there is a quote missing

```
<?php echo $_POST['url]; ?>
```

should be

```
<?php echo $_POST['url']; ?>
```

And for embeding a video if you just echo the url, it is not gonna embed.
You have to use the embed code for whatever kind of video it is for eg: Flash Player for flv/Flash Stream,WMP for wmv/asf streams,etc

You have to use the embed code and echo the url in the place were url is in the embed player

Comment: Yea, the missing quote was a typo and I just clarified the fact that I know just posting a URL isn't going to embed it, sorry for the misleading name. The problem is that even using the embed code nothing is showing up.

Comment: AH! Once again, it was because I was using Google Chrome, works perfectly in Firefox.

Comment: To work in Chrome there might be a other code or you will have to install the plugin